# When is ngOnInit method called?

Tags: angular

I have the following template

```
<div *ngIf="hotels$ | async as hotels; else loadGif ">
   <div *ngFor="let hotel of hotels | hotelsFilter: _filteredType; first as f; index as i " 
    appInit [hotel]="hotel " [first]="f ">
    <app-card appHighlight [hotel]=hotel></app-card>
   </div>
</div>
```

And appInit directive is written to idenify the fist element  of hotels list after the list is filtered. This is ngInit method of appInit directive:

```
  constructor(
        private __hotelsService: HotelsService
      ) { }

      @Input()
      public hotel: Hotel;
      @Input()
      public first: boolean;

      public ngOnInit(): void {
        if (this.first) {
          this.__hotelsService.selectedHotel$.next(this.hotel);
          console.log('first init ' + this.hotel.name);
        }else{
          console.log('not first init ' + this.hotel.name);
        }

      }
```

The problem is that `ngOnInit` method of the directive is called not each time when the list of hotels is filtered and re-rendered. The question is why and when ngOnInit is really should be called?

Answer (score 3):

Every time change detection runs and updates inputs that have a value bound to them `ngOnChanges` is called.
`ngOnInit` is called the first time after `ngOnChanges` is called.

For more details see https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

When `*ngFor` renders the elements, it recognizes when values are the same and reuses rendered items.
This is why `ngOnInit` is not called after the filter changes for items that were also rendered before the filter changed.

You can instead use `ngOnChanges` which will be called every time an input is updated, or you can make the inputs getters

```
  _first: boolean,
  @Input()
  public set first(value: boolean) {
    this._first = value;
    if (this.first) {
      this.__hotelsService.selectedHotel$.next(this.hotel);
      console.log('first init ' + this.hotel.name);
    }else{
      console.log('not first init ' + this.hotel.name);
    }
  }

  public get first() : boolean {
    return this._first;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

**ngOnInit** will only be called once when the component is initialized. As per your need, you should use **ngOnChanges** which will be called when input properties get changed.

For more info on lifecycle hooks: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks